# Merging 2 XML files looping on NodeList

Tags: java, xml

I have 2 xml files .. to e merged in 1 xml file

input files:

reference.xml

```
<company>
    <staff>
        <name>
            <surname>smith </surname>
        </name>
        <phone>465456433</phone>
        <email>gmail1</email>
    </staff>
</company>
```

comparison.xml

```
<company>
    <staff>
        <name>
            <initials>js</initials>
        </name>
        <area>area1</area>
        <city>city1</city>
    </staff>
</company>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <name>
             <surname>smith</surname>
             <initials>js</initials>
        </name>
        <phone>465456433</phone>
        <email>gmail1</email>
        <area>area1</area>
        <city>city1</city>
     </staff>
</company>
```

I get that output with a hardcoded code by getting tag names.. But is there a way to loop over each parent node and import its children from the 2 files without naming tags to be GENERIC

```
public class merge {

 public static void main(String[] args) {



    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    Document doc = null;
    Document doc2 = null;

    try {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new File("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/reference.xml"));
            doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/comparison.xml"));

            NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");


            Node nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("area").item(0), true);
            Node nodeCity = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0), true);
            ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
            ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeCity);


      NodeList ndList = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");

            Node nodesur =    doc.importNode(doc.getElementsByTagName("surname").item(0), true);
            Node nodein = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("initials").item(0), true);
            ndList.item(0).appendChild(nodesur);
            ndList.item(0).appendChild(nodein);


         ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
          Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
          transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  

          DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
          StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
          transformer.transform(source, result); 

          Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/final.xml"));
          String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();  
          output.write(xmlOutput);
          output.close();

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected result, if both documents have the same child node, but different values for the node? F.E.: in doc.xml `<company>
    <staff>...
        <email>foo@bar.com</email></staff></company>` and in doc2.xml `<company>
    <staff>...
        <email>bar@foo.com</email></staff></company>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
NodeList list = doc.getChildNodes();
```

But then you have to check each child to verify it is an element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Node n = list.item(i);
    if (n.getType().equals(Node.ELEMENT_NODE))
    {
        n.getNodeName();
    }
}
```

Something like that. To handle all elements in a document you have to use a Breadth/Depth First algorithm.

```
Stack<Node> pending = new Stack<Node>();
pending.push(doc.getChildNodes().item(0));
while(!pending.empty())
{
   Node n = pending.pop();
   n.getChildNodes();
   ...
}
```

It should be clear how to move on from here. If not I will work out a more working version when I have time.

Comment: your way can hold the root tag .. company .. can you get its children too? staff for example @cvesters

Comment: You will have to work recursively, or with an intelligent for loop (think Depth First/Breadth First) I will update my answer to match this.